# None of the currently installed provisioning profiles match app's bundle identifier?

Tags: ios, app-store, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to upload my iOS application in Visual Studio for Mac to the Apple App Store but I get this error message:

The error message in Visual Studio:
[image: Error message in VS]

The application works on my iPhone, therefore I'm surprised that I get this error message. In addition, I have setup an App ID in my Apple developer account and I have added an entry for a new app in App Store Connect.

The bundle identifier should be everywhere the same. So what is wrong?

Info.plist in Visual Studio(above) and App ID in my developer account:
[image: Visualstudioanddeveloperaccount]
App Store Connect, I added an entry for the application:
[image: Appstoreconnect]

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem. It was missing a distribution provisioning profile which you can create in the developer account. I had just a development profile.

[create provisioning profile](https://clearbridgemobile.com/how-to-create-a-distribution-provisioning-profile-for-ios/)

Comment: Link is dead mate